# How to get the true node value in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

So I have read in a network data in iGraph(R) and would like to store the nodes into a list. Here's what I have done:

```
G = read_graph("somegraph.graphml",format="graphml")
x = list(V(G)) 
> x
+ 15/15 vertices, from ecb3920:
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

My question is, how do I get the true value, i.e. the actually node id in my data, from `V(G)`. Thanks.

```
> dput(G)
structure(list(15, FALSE, c(13, 7, 9, 14, 10, 5, 4, 11, 6, 7, 
14, 4, 13, 9, 10, 5, 5, 13, 9, 6, 7, 14, 12, 10, 14, 10, 11, 
13, 9, 10, 12, 14, 8, 7, 11, 12, 8, 13, 14, 9, 11, 13, 13, 12, 
14, 10, 13, 12, 14, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14), c(0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 
10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13), c(6, 11, 5, 15, 16, 8, 19, 1, 9, 
20, 33, 32, 36, 2, 13, 18, 28, 39, 4, 14, 23, 25, 29, 45, 7, 
26, 34, 40, 22, 30, 35, 43, 47, 49, 0, 12, 17, 27, 37, 41, 42, 
46, 50, 51, 3, 10, 21, 24, 31, 38, 44, 48, 52, 53), c(1, 0, 6, 
5, 2, 4, 3, 11, 15, 8, 9, 13, 14, 7, 12, 10, 16, 19, 20, 18, 
23, 22, 17, 21, 25, 24, 33, 32, 28, 29, 26, 30, 27, 31, 36, 39, 
34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 41, 45, 43, 42, 44, 47, 46, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
52, 53), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 7, 11, 13, 18, 24, 28, 34, 44, 
54), c(0, 2, 2, 7, 16, 24, 26, 34, 40, 42, 46, 49, 51, 53, 54, 
54), list(c(1, 0, 1), structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), 
structure(list(id = c("1351920706", "500102244", "1454425532", 
"1625050630", "510838353", "1262640078", "681721364", "1351920717", 
"1260750116", "1524975171", "1070293410", "727198538", "715215233", 
"1351920666", "500920034")), .Names = "id"), list()), <environment>), class = "igraph")
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. `V(g)` already returns the vertex (node) ids.

Comment: Yea but in the data set, the nodes are 510838353 for example

Comment: Well, `V(g)` returns the vertex id. What are you trying to do? Please post a representative subsample of your graph (or code to produce a sample graph).

Comment: Please don't post data links to secondary file hosters. Many people are loath to download files from such sources (myself included). Instead [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52304555/edit) your post, and include sample data directly using `dput` (or provide code that generates sample data).

Comment: I have updated my question. Please let me know if you need any information.

Comment: Thanks, that's much better. The numbers `"1454425532"` and so on, *are* your vertex ids. The numbers you're seeing when you plot the graph are just index numbers of the vertices (they are *not* the vertex ids). So what numbers are you trying to extract?

Comment: I am trying to get the vertex ids.

Comment: **As I just explained: The vertex ids *are* the numbers `"1454425532"` and so on, that are returned by `V(G)!`**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179942/discussion-between-hina-and-maurits-evers).

Answer (score 1):

Just for closure (and to summarise from our chat): Based on the sample data you give, you can extract additional data for every vertex by indexing the corresponding element.

So

```
V(g)$id
```

returns

```
#[1] "1351920706" "500102244" "1454425532" "1625050630" "510838353" 
#[6] "1262640078" "681721364" "1351920717" "1260750116" "1524975171" 
#[11] "1070293410" "727198538" "715215233" "1351920666" "500920034"
```